# LinuxFX not installing

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation

I have downloaded "Windows Ubuntu 11.4.4 LTS" from the [LinuxFX downloads page](https://www.linuxfx.org/index.php/get/linuxfx), and created a bootable USB stick with UNetbootin. When I plug it in the OS starts up as normal.

Now to the problem. When I press "Installer" (it is in the Desktop folder), it says that it cannot install because there are no partitions to do so. This is strange, for I have an 80 GB volume connected.

Has anyone encountered this before? Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Does [FixParts](https://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) help?  If not, it sounds as if you've got [this going on](https://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions).  Read all the Answers not having to do with `FixParts`